# wpf c# datagrid GroupStyle - which rows are expanded

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, rows

I have the following WPF DataGrid with GroupStyle. I need to now which rows are expanded when I have expanded/collapsed event.

I add:

```
Expanded="Expander_Process"  Collapsed="Expander_Process"
```

but in the event function `Expander_Process` when I try to get the row

```
var row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(expander);
if (row == null)
```

then the `row` is null. So my question is: how can I know which rows are expanded in the datagrid?

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gvOptionChain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#FF262626" Foreground="White"  Width="1509" 
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              Margin="53,120,89,4.333" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" SelectionChanged="gvOptionChain_SelectionChanged"  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"  
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit ="Item" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization = "True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionUnit="Cell"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"  >


           <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="False" Foreground="#FFEEEEEE" Expanded="Expander_Process"  Collapsed="Expander_Process" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupItem}}, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=groupToTitleConverter}}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>


private void Expander_Process(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Expander expander)
    {
        var row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(expander);

        if (row == null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on the expander event - get the rows that expanded throu
CollectionViewGroup Items1 = ((CollectionViewGroup)(expander.DataContext));
and update a flag about the IsExpanded status of the row . this event happens many times for each expand - so I add timer to process the rows only once

```
  private System.Timers.Timer ExpandTimer;
    private bool bIsTimerOn = false;
    private void Expander_Process(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Expander expander)
        {
            CollectionViewGroup Items1 = ((CollectionViewGroup)(expander.DataContext));
            
            for(int i = 0; i < Items1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                OptScrtyData ScrtyData1 = (OptScrtyData)Items1.Items[i];
                ScrtyData1.IsExpanded = expander.IsExpanded;
            }
            if (bIsTimerOn == false)
            {
                ExpandTimer.Start();
                bIsTimerOn = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a better answer - activate the timer only if there is new expand status :
private void Expander_Process(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (sender is Expander expander)
{
CollectionViewGroup Items1 = ((CollectionViewGroup)(expander.DataContext));
bool bNewStatus = false;
for(int i = 0; i < Items1.Items.Count; i++)
{
OptScrtyData ScrtyData1 = (OptScrtyData)Items1.Items[i];
if (bNewStatus == false)
{
bNewStatus = ScrtyData1.IsExpanded != expander.IsExpanded;
}
ScrtyData1.IsExpanded = expander.IsExpanded;
}
if (bNewStatus == true)
{
ExpandTimer.Start();
}
}
}